# Trying to capture a line of data with Regex

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I am trying to capture this:

```
581116     03/20/12 08:42 87NL 10%ETH A        8,500 G GAL  3.189     27,106.50
```

and my regex is:

```
^(?<BOLNUM>\d+) +(?<LOADDATE>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}) +(?<LOADTIME>\d{2}:\d{2}) +#?(?<PRODUCTDESC>.*?)#? {2,}(?<QUANTITY>\S+) +(?<BASIS>G|N) +(?<UOM>\w{3}) +(?<PRICE>[\S]+)
```

But some of the files have a source of this:

```
581116     03/20/12 08:42 87NL 10%ETH A        8,500 G GAL3.189     27,106.50
```

Please observe that there is no gap between `GAL` and `3.189`. Can somebody help what will my regex to capture the above line? Please note that data can come in any of the above forms, so my regex should be able to capture the lines whether there is a gap between the fields (`GAL` and price fields).

Comment: I actually found the answer. Here it is

        (?<BOLNUM>\d+) +(?<LOADDATE>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}) +(?<LOADTIME>\d{2}:\d{2}) +#?(?<PRODUCTDESC>.*?)#? {2,}(?<QUANTITY>\S+) +(?<BASIS>G|N) +(?<UOM>\w{3})\s*(?<PRICE>\S+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert this last part:

```
(?<UOM>\w{3}) +(?<PRICE>[\S]+)
```

to this:

```
(?<UOM>\w{3}) *(?<PRICE>[\S]+)
```

The `*` make the space optional.

Comment: It should be this though. Thanks.  
  
        (?<UOM>\w{3}) \s*(?<PRICE>[\S]+)